# Leaflet search in Popup-Content?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I asked here https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/issues/242 but did not receive any answer. So: How can I create a search-box (with https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/) to show/open all markers with the search item within the Popup content?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please post your code here instead of linking to external resources. Also what have you tried so far to achieve a solution?

Comment: All markers are html elements which you can manipulate with JS

Answer (score 0):

Try put this code, before adding to map:

```
  //- Show popup (info window) if found
  controlSearch.on("search:locationfound", function (e) {
    if (e.layer._popup) e.layer.openPopup();
  });
```

It works for me, special thx to my boss :-)

The full search statement:

```
  //-- Searchbox
  var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements
  
  map.addLayer(markersLayer);

  var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
      position:'topleft',     
      layer: markersLayer,
      initial: false,
      zoom: 15,
      marker: false,
      clickable: true
  });

  //- Show popup (info window) if found
  controlSearch.on("search:locationfound", function (e) {
    if (e.layer._popup) e.layer.openPopup();
  });

  map.addControl(controlSearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet.Control.Search create an indexe of elements using by default the `title` field of the marker, more precisely in an instance of L.Marker  the title is found in `marker.options.title`.

L.Search searches for properties inside `options` in each markers
So you can append a new property in options which is linked to the corresponding popup content.

Then you can use the `propertyName` option to search in the new property you appended

```js
const markers = [marker1, marker2, marker3, ...]
//array of markers having popup content

//THE SOLUTION
markers.forEach(m => {
    m.options.popupText = m._popup._content
});

var poiLayers = L.layerGroup(markers).addTo(map);

L.control.search({
    layer: poiLayers,
    initial: false,
    propertyName: 'popupText'
})
.addTo(map);
```

Result:

[image]